Cursor jumps to end of lightning-input-rich-text value on initial click
I'm pre-populating a lightning-input-rich-text field on a Lightning Web Component with the value of a rich text field from the current record.  The first time a user clicks into this input field on the component, the cursor jumps to the very end of the field's pre-populated value.  While the component's open, any additional clicks into this field's value result in the cursor popping up exactly where the user clicked.  Is it possible to stop the cursor from jumping to the end on the very first click into this input-field?  I'm trying to figure out why the cursor jumps on the initial click and to stop this behavior from happening if possible.
Here's the html:
<div>
    <lightning-input-rich-text value={richTextValue} required>
    </lightning-input-rich-text>
</div>

Here's the JavaScript:
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import RICH_TEXT_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__Quote__c.Rich_Text_Example_Field__c";


const FIELDS = [RICH_TEXT_FIELD];

export default class OrderConfirmationEmail extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: "$recordId", fields: FIELDS})
    quote;

    get richTextValue() {
        return getFieldValue(this.quote.data, RICH_TEXT_FIELD);
    }

}

And here's a screenshot showing the result of what happens when I initially click into this input field's value.  No matter where I click, the cursor jumps to the very end of the value:


The method setRangeText() can be used to set the selectMode parameter to preserve, which is basically the default cursor focus value before inserting the text.
Calling this method at the beginning of the getter method seems the only option that works.
get richTextValue() {        
    const editor = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-rich-text');
    if(editor){
        editor.setRangeText(
        '', undefined, undefined, 'preserve'
        );
    }
    return getFieldValue(this.quote.data, RICH_TEXT_FIELD);
}

Note: at this current time, this method is marked as beta.
More info from the chapter "Inserting Text Programmatically (Beta)" here: lightning-input-rich-text

This works perfectly, Shamina.  Thank you!
